# Cannot convert a string from scraping to a currency with Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping

I have the following to get the price of a product as a string:

```
if price is not None:
    price_text = price.text.strip()
```

I tried to do

```
    price_text = Decimal(price.text.strip()) * 1.24
```

but it is not working

What I am doing wrong?

Additionally I get the price as `40.90`, even if the the string is `40,90`.

Comment: Be precise. What's the value of `price.text.strip()`? What's the value you want in `price_text`?

Comment: I want the 40,90 to be multiplied with 1,24

Comment: So price.text.string() value is 40,90 or 40.90? It makes difference

Comment: when i do print(price_text) and export to csv is 40.90

Comment: And what error you get with `Decimal(price.text.strip())*1.24`?

Comment: TypeError: sequence item 1: expected str instance tuple found

Comment: Then it is easy. `price.text.strip()` is a tuple, not a string. So it is not 40.90. Check its value again.